# Html page automatically refreshes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am creating a PHP page using Javascript. I created an HTML form, and called a PHP part of the code. When I display the JSON array, I can see the displayed elements for a millisecond and then the page refreshes to the initial page. The code works, but I don't want the automatic refresh. How do I do that?

HTML:

```html
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h1>ADD INVNTORY</h1>
  <form action='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <span class="number">1</span>
        Your basic info
      </legend>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="product_name"/> 
      <label for="serial">Serial number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="serial" name="serial"/>
      <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount"/>  
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h1>VIEW ALL</h1>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <span class="number">1</span>
        Current Inventory list
      </legend>
      <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Show all">
      <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content">
        <h1 id="here"></h1>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h1>VIEW INVENTORY DETAILS(GRAPH)</h1>
    <fieldset></fieldset>
  </div> 
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $nname = "";
    $sserial = "";
    $aamount = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (empty($_POST["product_name"])) {
        {
          echo "Name is required";  
          break;
        }
      } else {
        $nname = test_input($_POST["product_name"]);
      }
      if (empty($_POST["serial"])) {
        {
          echo "Serial code is required";
          break;
        }
      } else {
        $sserial = test_input($_POST["serial"]);
      }
      if (empty($_POST["amount"])) {
        {
          echo "Amount is required";
          break;
        }
      } else {
        $aamount = test_input($_POST["amount"]);
      }
      insertdata($nname,$sserial,$aamount);
    }
  }
  function test_input($data) {
    return $data;
  }
  function insertdata($nname,$sserial,$aamount) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO inventory_list (name, serialno, amount)  VALUES ('$nname', '$sserial', '$aamount')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
  } 
  if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "mydb";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT * from inventory_list";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $return_arr=array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // output data of each row
      while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
        $row_array['serialno'] = $row['serialno'];
        $row_array['amount'] = $row['amount'];
        array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
      }    
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
  }
?>
```

^^ the php part,

Javascript:

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($return_arr);?>, out = "<table>";

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  out += "<tr><td>" + 
    arr[i].name +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].serialno +
    "</td><td>" +
    arr[i].amount +
    "</td></tr>";
}

out += "</table>";
document.querySelector("#myPopup #here").innerHTML = out;
```

Comment: there is no code above that could refresh the page

Comment: Are you trigging a form submission somewhere outside the code you provided?

Comment: As @Dagon says, nothing here could cause the behavior you have described.

Comment: you say you are using jQuery but there is no evidence of a jQuery fnction. There is however a `submit` button which, as you would expect, submits the form - with a full page load.

Comment: hmm , i'll edit in the php part of the code as well ? maybe that'll help

Comment: Show the javascript, that's likely to be the culprit

Answer (score 2):

The auto-refresh is from using the input type="submit". A button or input with the type equaling "submit" will automatically refresh when the button is pressed.

To fix this problem, either change the input's type to "button" or use the jQuery preventDefault function when the button is clicked.

The documentation for the preventDefault function:
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you bind the form using jQuery, you can return false to prevent the form from submitting/refreshing or use preventDefault()

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/